# What's the real value for com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge in Mojarra

Tags: jsf, mojarra

The default value referenced in Mojarra docs (https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.0.4/whatsnew.html) is 604800 (sec ?) but in Balusc blog and in other places in stackoverflow we can see 604800000. So what is the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

The value is configured in WebConfiguration (in mojarra 2.2)

```
DefaultResourceMaxAge(
          "com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge",
          "604800000" // 7 days
    )
```